# Deployment of OpenStack with Autopilot excessively slow (or perhaps nonfunctional)?

Tags: maas, openstack, cloud, openstack-autopilot, conjure-up

I'm having some trouble with an OpenStack Autopilot deployment. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with MAAS and `conjure-up` (according to the installation guide). I have a controller node and seven servers that I can deploy successfully with MAAS (in other words, I meet the requirements of the guide). Once I reach the "Conjuring up OpenStack with NovaKVM" page, which displays all of the services and requirements, however, the installation hangs or fails completely. According to the documentation, [this step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAUTi.png) should take minutes; I usually have to stop it after several hours and I don't think it's ever gone to completion.

Two of my servers [fail deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl4Qa.png). The rest proceed normally. I'm not quite sure what to make of the error message: it's present only on servers that have multiple disks. I'm not sure what would cause it to fail, though, as the servers passed all the MAAS hardware tests (one with a nonfunctional disk did not, but the complaints stopped when it was replaced). The full error message follows:

```
curtin: Installation started. (0.1.0~bzr505-0ubuntu1~17.04.1)

third party drivers not installed or necessary.

  Failed to find logical volume "vg_peaks/lv_swap"

  Failed to find logical volume "vg_peaks/lv_scratch"

Failed to exclusively open path: /dev/sda1

Device holders with exclusive access: ['dm-0', 'dm-1']

Device mounts: []

Possible users of /dev/sda1:

None

Failed to exclusively open path: /dev/sda1

Device holders with exclusive access: ['dm-0', 'dm-1']

Device mounts: []

Possible users of /dev/sda1:

None

Failed to exclusively open path: /dev/sda1

Device holders with exclusive access: ['dm-0', 'dm-1']

Device mounts: []

Possible users of /dev/sda1:

None

Failed to exclusively open path: /dev/sda1

Device holders with exclusive access: ['dm-0', 'dm-1']

Device mounts: []

Possible users of /dev/sda1:

None

[Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/sda1'

curtin: Installation failed with exception: Unexpected error while running command.

Command: ['curtin', 'block-meta', 'custom']

Exit code: 3

Reason: -

Stdout:   Failed to find logical volume "vg_peaks/lv_swap"

          Failed to find logical volume "vg_peaks/lv_scratch"

        Failed to exclusively open path: /dev/sda1

        Device holders with exclusive access: ['dm-0', 'dm-1']

        Device mounts: []

        Possible users of /dev/sda1:

        None

        Failed to exclusively open path: /dev/sda1

        Device holders with exclusive access: ['dm-0', 'dm-1']

        Device mounts: []

        Possible users of /dev/sda1:

        None

        Failed to exclusively open path: /dev/sda1

        Device holders with exclusive access: ['dm-0', 'dm-1']

        Device mounts: []

        Possible users of /dev/sda1:

        None

        Failed to exclusively open path: /dev/sda1

        Device holders with exclusive access: ['dm-0', 'dm-1']

        Device mounts: []

        Possible users of /dev/sda1:

        None

        [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/sda1'



Stderr: ''
```

I suppose, then, that this is truly two questions:

1. How long should the installation process take? Is there any way to see what is happening? The log files didn't seem particularly useful.
2. What might be the cause of the failed deployments? This does not happen when deploying the servers with MAAS. It's only present when using the `conjure-up` tool.

Any and all information would be much appreciated. I've hit a wall with the installation at this point and need some guidance on how to proceed. I'd be happy to provide more information or test things as needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the deployment of software by Juju, which is hardware-agnostic. It attempted to deploy Ceph on servers with a single disk. Though I'm sure this could be remedied by selecting the hosts for each program, we merely added a second disk to each server and the issues resolved themselves.